# iPhone POST request with JSON data

Tags: objective-c, json, mongodb, http, post

I am building my first iPhone application and have run into problems trying to POST json data to my MongoDB database.

This is my code thus far:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"name\":\"blah\"&\"reputation\":\"100\"&\"phone_number\":\"1234\"}"];
        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myURL/users"]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        //[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSData *POSTReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
        NSString *theReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[POSTReply bytes] length:[POSTReply length] encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Reply: %@", theReply);
```

I get this response in the console:

```
2014-06-10 16:07:09.758 SocialEyez[2226:70b] Reply: {
  "_id": "5397656dd7ec395c1b808230"
}
```

So even though the POST seems to go through fine, there is something wrong with my formatting which prevents the JSON data from being entered. 
I've tried to format the NSString a hundred different ways but nothing seems to work.

Please help me out!!

EDIT:

When I send this request over jQuery:

```
jQuery.post("http://site/users", { "name": "George Washington", "reputation": "pres", "phone_number": "1234" }, function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { console.log("Post resposne:"); console.dir(data); console.log(textStatus); console.dir(jqXHR); });
```

I get the following response:

```
_id: "53978f4cd7ec395c1b808247"
name: "George Washington"
reputation: "pres"
phone_number: "1234"
```

Comment: perhaps tell us what "postData" is right before you "setHTTPBody". Just put a breakpoint at that line and print the value of postData to the console (po postData). That may help us see formatting errors. Although you are getting a response of an ID, what were you expecting to get back?

Comment: When printing out "postData" I get the following:
<7b226e61 6d65223a 22626c61 68227d>

When sending the same request over jquery, I get back a response with the _id, name, reputation, and phone_number. 

_id is returned even if the httpBody is blank.

Comment: What you are getting is the hexadecimal representation on the bytes, you are probably more used to the ASCII representation which is: {"name":"blah"}. Somewhere along the line you may need to understand hexadecimal, now might be a good tie to learn it.

Comment: Notice the difference between your string the the jQuery string. Try validating your JSON with a validator on the web.

Answer (score 1):

This example assumes that the post data should be JSON.

Create the JSON from a dictionary, let `NSJSONSerialization` add the JSON syntax.

```
// @"{\"name\":\"blah\"&\"reputation\":\"100\"&\"phone_number\":\"1234\"}"

// Create the dictionary
NSDictionary *postDict = @{@"name":@"blah", @"reputation":@"100", @"phone_number":@"1234"};

// Create the JSON data
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDict options:0 error:&error];

// Just for this example: display the jsonData as an ASCII string
NSLog(@"jsonData as String: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

NSLog output:

```
jsonData: <7b226e61 6d65223a 22626c61 68222c22 72657075 74617469 6f6e223a 22313030 222c2270 686f6e65 5f6e756d 62657222 3a223132 3334227d>

jsonData as String: {"name":"blah","reputation":"100","phone_number":"1234"}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out! Try to bear with me here...
When printing postDict as defined by your answer I get some weird formatting... 
{
    name = blah;
    "phone_number" = 1234;
    reputation = 100;
}
Im not sure why only "phone _number" is being wrapped in parenthesis. 

Also, since HTTPBody is composed of hex data, do I have to modify my NodeJS API to decode the hex back into UTF-8?

Comment: What you are seeing is the way the `NSDictionary` description method displays it's contents, do not put to much faith in where it places quote marks. If you want to check the actual types extract them and check them.